# Deteching if child already exists inside parent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a Userscript for my use on StackOverflow, that basically replaces all images with a copy of the same image from a proxy.

What I want is for all of the image links posted in comments to be added to a new container inside the comment called imageContainer that should be created if it doesn't already exist, then all images should be moved to this container.

What I have currently sort of works - except for every image in a comment, a new container is created.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length ; i++) {
    var matches = containsAny(links[i].href, matchURLs);
    if(matches) {
        //link variables
        var link = links[i];
        var linkParent = links[i].parentNode;

        console.log(linkParent);

        //create <img> element
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = proxy + link.href;
        image.height = 50;
        image.width = 50;

        //alter <a> element
        link.href = proxy + link.href;
        link.target = "_blank";
        link.innerHTML = "";
        link.style.borderBottom = "none";

        //attach <img> to <a>
        link.appendChild(image);

        var result = linkParent.contains(document.getElementById("imageContainer"));
        console.log(result);
        if(!result) {
            //create imageContainer (div) element
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            container.id = "imageContainer";
            linkParent.prepend(container);
        }
        //append image to container that exists from last check
        linkParent.querySelector("#imageContainer").appendChild(link);
    }
}
```

This line:

```
var result = linkParent.contains(document.getElementById("imageContainer"));
```

always results in `false`, even if I have already created the container on the previous loop, which means a new div is created for every image that is converted by the code, which makes it much harder for me to format correctly.

Basically, the current code will generate the following HTML in the comment I am testing this on:

```
<span class="comment-copy">
    <div id="imageContainer"><a href="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" style="border-bottom: none;"><img src="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" height="50" width="50"></a></div>
    <div id="imageContainer"><a href="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" style="border-bottom: none;"><img src="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" height="50" width="50"></a></div>
    currently testing my new userscript (relevant to discussion)  
</span>
```

As you can see, it contains 2 copies of the div `imageContainer`, even though the loop I have should check if it exists, and only create it if it *doesn't*.

The result I expect is as followed:

```
<span class="comment-copy">
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <a href="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" style="border-bottom: none;"><img src="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" height="50" width="50"></a>
        <a href="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" style="border-bottom: none;"><img src="http://web.archive.org/web/https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" height="50" width="50"></a>
    </div>
    currently testing my new userscript (relevant to discussion)  
</span>
```

The script is being run from tampermonkey on page load.

Why is a new div created for every link?

### A Discovery:

There is a variable that is mentioned in the code above called `matchURLs` - I've just discovered the weirdest thing.

This variable is defined as

```
var matchURLs = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/", "https://i.imgur.com/"];
```

it's basically just the URLs to check if the image is from (I don't want to proxy every image, only ones from the URLs above)

But the weird part of this is, if I remove the second link from the array, e.g if I define matchURLs as

```
var matchURLs = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/"];
```

then the code works as expected and puts all of the images inside a single imageContainer div instead of multiple divs. Is this the cause of the issue? Why?

The `containsAny()` function is defined as:

```
function containsAny(str, substrings) {
    for (var i = 0; i != substrings.length; i++) {
       if(str.startsWith(substrings[i])) {
         return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's any help but your containsAny function works correctly for me in chrome with either the 1 or 2 element array. https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/YexGyG

Comment: @JasonB Me too, the issue seems to be with checking if the child exists in the parent

Comment: If you call `links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); link = links[i];  linkParent = links[i].parentNode;` in the loop immediately before that call to `linkParent.contains()` does it see the child element?

Comment: @JasonB I'm not really following you there, I'm sorry. I don't think I can call that inside the loop

Comment: You don't redeclare links, link, or parentLink, but you grab a new set of values from the DOM. The index `i` should still work because you aren't modifying the number of links right? My thought is that somehow one of these values may have a reference to the unedited content. Refreshing these values from the DOM right before the one that doesn't work might fix the problem ( though I'm not sure about that...)

Comment: @JasonB that's incorrect because `link` and `linkParent` are declared on every loop iteration. `links` is declared before the loop as that is what the loop is actually going through

Comment: When you console.log linkParent are you seeing the #imageContainer in there?

Comment: @JasonB Here is what I get _with_ the 2nd link added, where it is not working: http://i64.tinypic.com/35n8ntj.png --- Here is what I get with only 1 link, and it works: http://i68.tinypic.com/24mgxm8.png

Comment: I think I see it. Document.getElementById is grabbing the first one on the page so linkParent doesn't contain it.

Comment: @JasonB So how can I check if the element exists within the parent of the link?

Comment: Use a class instead of id and check something like parentLink.querySelector ('myClass').length

Comment: @JasonB I tried this code: `var result = linkParent.querySelector('.comment-copy').length;` and got error `ERROR: Execution of script 'Image Proxier' failed! Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parentLink.querySelector( '.image-container' )` to try and select the image container that is a child of the `.comment-copy` element. If it is null, it doesn't exist, otherwise you have a reference to that element.

Run the snippet to see the first and third comment returning the proper element with innerHTML 1 and 3 respectively and the second comment returning null because the image container doesn't exist yet.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  var linkParent = links[i].parentNode;

  result = linkParent.querySelector('.image-container');

  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<span class="comment-copy">
    this comment has some links like <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" >image</a> and <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" >image</a>
        <div class="image-container">1</div>
</span>

<span class="comment-copy">
    this comment has some links like <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" >image</a> and <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" >image</a>
</span>

<span class="comment-copy">
    this comment has some links like <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" >image</a> and <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WNI.png" >image</a>
        <div class="image-container">3</div>
</span>
```

Comment: GrumpyC - I think this should get it working - but I thought I should stop polluting the question comments even if it doesn't fix it for you!

Comment: If you are interested in the results of this at all, check out my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363345/5827005).

Comment: Nice! Glad to see you got it working, and see the final product.